# Way to increment objects inside an array for 2 hit detection c+

Tags: c++, sdl, this

Im creating a basic game using SDL/C++. I need a way to implement 2 hit detection. When just trying one hit it works fine. Here is what i have for the two hit detection:

```
  int maxHit = 2;
  int hitCount = 0;

  // Detect collisions
  for(auto p : projectiles) {
    for(auto a : aliens) {

    if(p->CollidesWith(a) && hitCount == maxHit)
    {
        p->HandleCollision();
        a->HandleCollision();       
    }  
        if(p->CollidesWith(a) && hitCount != maxHit) {  
        ++hitCount; 
      }
    }

  }
```

For some reason it works on a select few of the enemies on the screen and doesn't for others.

EDITED TO MAKE IT CLEARER

Comment: I think your question needs rewording and you've to correlate more between the code and the description that accompanies it e.g. which class is the code in? I see no notion of `this` in this chunk.

Comment: Yeah sorry, changed the way it was formatted.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `this` identifies the object on which the method was called. In C++ if you use the `this` keyword explicitly when accessing a member, you need the `->` access operator instead of `.` because it is a pointer, not a reference.

But, of course, you would usually just write `++ hits` with no `this`.

Comment: Yeah sorry. Made it more clear to what I am asking. Need to implement a hot counter for two hits.

Comment: @user3463583 The edit makes it wrong. `hitCount` should be a property of the objects, and `++ hitCount` should be inside `handleCollision`.